# post method on two actions within same controller in laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

Following is my route file i.e **web.php**

```
Route::post('finddomainname','DomainController@finddomainname')->name('finddomainname');

Route::post('registerdomains','DomainController@registerdomains')->name('registerdomains');
```

Following is the code on my **DomainController** for both the actions used,

```
public function finddomainname(Request $request)
{
    $this->validate($request,
        ['searchdomaintxt'=>'required',
        'searchdomainext'=>'required']);

    $searchdomaintxt    =  $request->input('searchdomaintxt');
    $searchdomainext    =  $request->input('searchdomainext');
    $domainname="";
    if($searchdomaintxt && $searchdomainext)
    {   
        foreach($searchdomainext as $ext)
        {
            $domainname.=$searchdomaintxt.".".$ext.",";
        }

        //dd($domainnames);
        $domainnames= rtrim($domainname,',');

        $response=$this->soap->multidomainsearch($domainnames);
        $result=$response['RESPONSE']['DOMAINSEARCH'];
        //dd($result);
        if($result){
            //return redirect()->action('searchresults', array('response' => $result));
            return view('domain.searchresults',['response'=>$result]);
        }
        else
        {
            return view('domain.searchresults',['response'=>'']);
        }


    }
}
```

Following is the second action on which control come after submitting data

```
public function registerdomains(registerDomainsValidation $request)
{       

    $domains=$request->input('selecteddomains');
    $selectedyear =$request->input('selectedyear');
    $domaincontactid=\Session::get('domaincontactid');
    $alldomains='';
    foreach($domains as $domain)
    {
        $alldomains.=$domain.",";
    }
    $alldomains=rtrim($alldomains,',');
    $response=$this->soap->registerdomains($alldomains,$domaincontactid,$selectedyear);
    return view('domain.searchresults',['response'=>$response]);
}
```

but when i  submit data it will show me this error

```
    protected function methodNotAllowed(array $others)
{
    throw new MethodNotAllowedHttpException($others);
}
```

Comment: POST REDIRECT GET

Comment: your are correct, but what is the way around to avoid this problem,if i submit a **form-1** with post request and **form-2** is generated from **form-1** submitted data and now if i post the **form-2** data it will show method not allowed exception....any example on this problem in laravel?

Comment: because you are not POSTing then REDIRECTing to a GET route

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access your `POST` route using a `GET` request, that's why you are receiving a `MethodNotAllowedHttpException`. To solve this issue, make sure that your `<form></form>` tag contains the appropriate `method` attribute.

```
<form action="{{ YOUR_URL }}" method="POST">
    ...
</form>
```

Or if you want to perform the request **inside** your controller, you can use `Guzzle` to send http requests. In your controller you can do:

```
use GuzzleHttp\Client;

$client = new Client();
$response = $client->request('POST', 'YOUR_URL', [
    'form_params' => [
        'foo' => 'bar'
    ]
]);
```

Comment: but i m using the post method in my form 
<form id="myform" method="post"  action="{{route('registerdomains')}}" >

Comment: Can you confirm what line is causing you the issue?

Comment: I believe it's this line of code `$response=$this->soap->registerdomains($alldomains,$domaincontactid,$selectedyear);`

Comment: not at all , control come to this action and this action run correctly , but if i place validation then it shows MethodNotAllowedHttpException error

Comment: Basically control comes on **finddomainname** action with post request and then i again using post request to go to **registerdomains** action...there is some post get  problem with laravel but i donot know how to tackle this ...i m new in laravel